# How to listen to a specific button with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, keylistener

To catch a button pressing (let's say Esc as an example), I currently use:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) { ... });
```

To my understanding, this will run after every key press that the user makes, and if the logic behind my function is heavy that doesn't sound very efficient.

Is there a way to listen only to the desired key?

To clarify, I am using an `if(e.keyCode == ...) { ... }` statement, but still, if I have a lot of listeners, even a switch case statement doesn't sound very efficient.

Comment: well what do you expect? `enterUp, enterDown, escUp,  escDown` etc  hundreds of key specific events?

Comment: Maybe... I was thinking about something more like the `$("#...").on(..., ...);` statement...

Comment: there is no other way to do this, you have to use the (keyup) event for these kind of things, and use the keycode to run your code if for example the esc button is pressed.

Comment: I'm afraid not, but you can addEventListener/removeEventListener (or bind/unbind with JQUery) if you are afraid of having too many listeners attached to the DOM at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot bind to a specific key press. You can only bind to key presses/downs in general and *then* interrogate which key it was.

This need not be overly computationally expensive provided your function does nothing except where the desired keys are involved.

Comment: Is there a JS alternative?

Comment: No - I was talking about JS.

Answer (score 1):

> To clarify, I am using an if(e.keyCode == ...) { ... } statement, but still, if I have a lot of listeners, even a switch case statement doesn't sound very efficient.

To avoid a long switch-case, you can use an object key-value pair. So, something like this would be good:

```
var obj = {  // here `key ---> key-code`, and `value --> functionToCall`
    "47" : someFunc,  
    "48" : someFunc2,
    "49" : someFunc3,
    ....  // you get the idea
};

function someFunc3(){
    alert("great!"); 
}

// testing
obj[49](); // outputs great!
```

So, you can use this global object like this:

```
document.getElementById("myElement").onkeydown = function(e){

   if( obj.hasOwnProperty(e.keyCode) ) 
       obj[e]();
   else 
       alert("Not found");
}
```

Best thing, you can use it anywhere, in any function, as it would be global.

Hope that helps!